# Number of square pieces

Tags: combinatorics

Sal cuts a square of integer side length into smaller squares of integer side length. For example, she might cut a $4*4$ square into four  $1*1$ squares and three $2*2$ squares, making 7 pieces.

[image: 7 square pieces]

A. Draw a diagram to show how Sal can cut a $5*5$ square into 11 square pieces.

I've completed this one. I was just wondering is there a formula or proof to show the relation?

[image: 11 square pieces]

B. Show that Sal can't cut a $4*4$ square into 11 pieces

I've done this by showing all of the possible cuts for a $4*4$ square, however that's not very convenient. Is there some sort of formula/shortcut/proof for it?

C. Sal has 2 $4*4$ squares, 3 $3*3$ squares, 4 $2*2$ squares and 4 $1*1$ squares. Draw a diagram showing how she can place all or some of these squares together without gaps or overlaps to make the largest square possible. Explain why she cannot  construct a larger square.

Here is where I'm having problems. This question almost certainly requires the use of proofs, and I'm not very good at those. So is there some proof I can use to make the biggest square possible and why isn't there a bigger square.
Thanks.

Comment: I assume in your 2nd last paragraph you mean 'Explain why she Cannot make a larger square'?

Comment: @rt6 edited it thanks

Comment: A duplicate of a problem from a running contest. Deleting while investigating. Will unlock on July 7th.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen there is [another instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2279165/59379) of this question your forget to unlock.

Comment: Sorry about that @achillehui. Now unlocked and undeleted. Should one be closed as a dupe of the other? What do you think?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - the other question is somewhat of a subset of this (part C) but the accepted answer here only cover (part B). It seems the best action is merge the questions and answers. However, it doesn't seem easy to merge the questions. Maybe we should just close the other as a dupe of this with a custom instead of "already has an answer" reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relating to your Question B, one can prove that a configuration of $11$ squares from a $4\times 4$ square is not possible.

From our $4\times 4$ square, we can only cut out $1\times 1$, $2\times 2$, $3\times 3$ and a $4\times 4$ squares. Call the number of squares of each of these sizes $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ respectively.

We need to have $a+b+c+d=11\qquad (*)$

However, it is clear that we would need to have $c=d=0$ since if either of these were $1$, then we cannot have $(*)$ being satisfied as we would either have none or not enough other squares to make up $11$ in total. Also, we could obviously not have $c,d\geq 1$ since we are only working with a $4\times 4$ square.

So $(*)$ reduces to $a+b=11$.

Looking at the picture of the $4\times 4$ square you posted, notice that we have $b\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and further notice that no matter what number for $b$ we choose, there will always then only be an even number of $1\times 1$ squares left.

Further, note that $11$ is an odd number.

Since the sum of an odd and an even is always odd. We are forced to choose an odd number of $2\times 2$ squares to ensure our answer for $(*)$ is also odd. I.e., we must have $b\in \{1,3\}$. Its easy to verify that, by the picture, the sum of $1\times 1$ squares added to the either $1$ or $3$ $2\times 2$ squares can never add up to $11$.

As for Question C, if we add up the number of $1\times 1$ squares that we have available is $2\times 4^2+ 3\times 3^2+ 4\times 2^2+ 4\times 1^2=79$ the next smallest square number from $79$ is $8^2=64$ and the next largest is $9^2=81$.

So the largest square we can hope to construct is a $8\times 8$ square.

Comment: What does the e-like shape mean before the matrix?

Comment: Can you please add a diagram for question C as it will help?

Comment: It means $b$ is 'an element of'. In other words, all the possible values that $b$ can take on, it must one of that list of numbers.

Comment: For question c, I cannot seem to make a 8*8 square. I can make a 7*7 square though. When we took away the thirteen squares, how many formations did we actually take away?

Comment: By the guidelines of Maths StackExchange, it is considered unsound to provide full answers to homework questions.